# A subset of a metric space is open iff it is a union of open neighborhoods.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

May someone please verify if this proof is correct?
Let E be the union of open neighborhoods, since the union of a collection of open sets is open, it follows that E is an open set. Assume E is an open set therefore, $\forall$ p$\in$ E $\exists$ $r>0$ : $N_r(p)$ $\subset$ E. So for $p_1$ , $\exists$ $N_{r_1}(p_1)$ $\subset$ E and the same thing  holds for every p. This means that every element in E has a neighborhood around it, therefore, E is contained within the union of the neighborhoods.
Furthermore, may someone please tell me of possible ways to improve this proof?

Comment: No proof is needed, because the very **definition** of an open set in a metric space is a set which is a union of open balls.

Comment: But is what I said, equivalent to the definition?

Comment: Furthermore, is the union of neighborhoods necessarily a neighborhood?

Comment: The definition of an open set, similar to any mathematical definition, allows you to *automatically* translate back and forth between the two statements "$E$ is open" and "$E$ is a union of open balls", without any proof. That's what definitions do.

Comment: @LeeMosher that's not the definition Rudin gives. And it's pretty clear from the question that mathsssislife isn't using your definition.

Comment: I was hoping that you might tell us what definitions you are using, because what I wrote is indeed the standard definition of open (see for example the answer of @AlbertoTakase, or [the wikipedia page on metric spaces,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Open_and_closed_sets,_topology_and_convergence) or other textbooks such as the one by Munkres). So if Rudin is starting with a different definition, we will need to know that in order to provide a useful answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You asked if it is possible to improve your proof that an open set is the union of open sets.

**Notation.** Let $(M,\rho)$ be a metric space. Fix $x_0\in M$. Fix $r>0$.
"$B(x_0,r)$" is notation for "$\{x\in M:\rho(x,x_0)<r\}$."

**Terminology.** Let $(M,\rho)$ be a metric space. Fix $S\subseteq M$. Say $S$ is *open* if for each $x\in S$, there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq S$.

**Proposition.** Let $(M,\rho)$ be a metric space. Fix $S\subseteq M$. The following are equivalent.

- (i) $S$ is open.
- (ii) $S=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha$, where $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a family of open sets.

*Proof.*

($\Rightarrow$) Assume $S$ is open. Then $S=\bigcup_{x\in S}B(x,r_x)$, where $r_x>0$ and $B(x,r_x)\subseteq S$ for every $x\in S$. Because $B(x,r_x)$ is open for every $x\in S$, we are done.

($\Leftarrow$) Assume $S=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha$, where $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a family of open sets. To prove $S$ is open, fix $x_0\in S$. Then $x_0\in U_{\alpha_0}$ for some $\alpha_0\in A$. Because $U_{\alpha_0}$ is open, there exists $r_0>0$ such that $B(x_0,r_0)\subseteq U_{\alpha_0}$. Because $S=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha$, it follows that $B(x_0,r_0)\subseteq S$. As a result, $S$ is open.